# Counting distinct words in a speech using tagset in nltk

Tags: python, nltk, tokenize, pos-tagger

I am currently having trouble with this.

I was given a task is to implement a function that return a sorted list of distinct words with a given part of speech. I am required to use NLTK's pos_tag_sents and NLTK's tokeniser to count the specific words.

I had a similar question to this and got it working thanks to some help from other users from Stack Overflow. And trying to use the same method to solve this problem.

Here is what I have have so far in my code:

```
import nltk
import collections
nltk.download('punkt')
nltk.download('gutenberg')
nltk.download('brown')
nltk.download('averaged_perceptron_tagger')
nltk.download('universal_tagset')

def pos_counts(text, pos_list):
    """Return the sorted list of distinct words with a given part of speech
    >>> emma = nltk.corpus.gutenberg.raw('austen-emma.txt')
    >>> pos_counts(emma, ['DET', 'NOUN'])
    [14352, 32029] - expected result
    """

    text = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
    tempword = nltk.pos_tag_sents(text, tagset="universal")
    counts = nltk.FreqDist(tempword)

    return [counts[x] or 0 for x in pos_list]
```

There are a doctest that should give the result of: [14352, 32029]

I ran my code and got this error message:

```
Error
**********************************************************************
File "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/a1/a1.py", line 29, in a1.pos_counts
Failed example:
    pos_counts(emma, ['DET', 'NOUN'])
Exception raised:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.3.4\helpers\pycharm\docrunner.py", line 140, in __run
        compileflags, 1), test.globs)
      File "<doctest a1.pos_counts[1]>", line 1, in <module>
        pos_counts(emma, ['DET', 'NOUN'])
      File "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/a1/a1.py", line 35, in pos_counts
        counts = nltk.FreqDist(tempword)
      File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\a1\venv\lib\site-packages\nltk\probability.py", line 108, in __init__
        Counter.__init__(self, samples)
      File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\collections\__init__.py", line 535, in __init__
        self.update(*args, **kwds)
      File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\a1\venv\lib\site-packages\nltk\probability.py", line 146, in update
        super(FreqDist, self).update(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\collections\__init__.py", line 622, in update
        _count_elements(self, iterable)
    TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

I feel I'm getting close but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Any help will be very appreciated. 
Thank you.

Comment: Three suggestions: 1. Indent your code correctly 2. Include your stack trace as text not picture 3. You only need to run `nltk.download` once, so including it in your mcve is not necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it would be like this:

```
import nltk

def pos_count(text, pos_list):
    sents = nltk.tokenize.sent_tokenize(text)
    words = (nltk.word_tokenize(sent) for sent in sents)
    tagged = nltk.pos_tag_sents(words, tagset='universal')
    tags = [tag[1] for sent in tagged for tag in sent]
    counts = nltk.FreqDist(tag for tag in tags if tag in pos_list)
    return counts
```

It's all very well explained in the [nltk book](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch05.html). Test:

```
In [3]: emma = nltk.corpus.gutenberg.raw('austen-emma.txt')

In [4]: pos_count(emma, ['DET', 'NOUN'])
Out[4]: FreqDist({'DET': 14352, 'NOUN': 32029})
```

**EDIT**: it's a good idea to use `FreqDist` when you need to count things such as part of speech tags. I don't think it's very clever to have a function return a plain list with results, in principle how would you know which number represent which tag?

A possible (imho bad) solution is to return a sorted list of `FreqDist.values()`. This way the results are sorted in accordance with alphabetic order of the tag names. If you really want this replace `return counts` with `return [item[1] for item in sorted(counts.items())]`in the definition of the function above.

Comment: The results I got were: [FreqDist({'DET': 14263}), FreqDist({'NOUN': 32070})] and not [14352, 32029]

Comment: Well I tried your re-edited code and the output says "got nothing"

Comment: the numbers should result in [14352, 32029], i got different numbers from ur old code, the one u had before re-editted

Comment: I tried your code once more and got FreqDist({'NOUN': 32070, 'DET': 14263})

Comment: I tried it I got this: FreqDist({'NOUN': 32029, 'DET': 14352}). The numbers are right but the Freq... is still there

Comment: @Ovaflow Well, if you want a list just cast `FreqDist.values()` to list. Please accept my answer if it helped you.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, do you mean change the def pos_counts? Because I'm not really allowed to change that since this is a task i was given. Would you mind showing me where I need to change in order to get the results as a list?

Comment: @Ovaflow well, casting your `dict.values()` to list is really basic Python, but there you go, I've edited the answer. It's a good idea to read Python tutorial, especially the [Data Structures](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) part.

Comment: well I'm don't know why but I get [32029, 14352] and not [14352, 32029], I'm getting the results backwards

Comment: Also you used text as a variable twice, wouldnt that confuse the function?

Comment: I'm still getting [32029, 14352] for some reason and I still don't know why? Looking at the code really carefully but can't seem to know what's causing this

Comment: @Ovaflow I've added a paragraph to my answer, it explains what you need to do. You don't have to worry about using variables twice in such a context. AFAIK your new name only gets assigned after the evaluation of the previous function. Nevertheless I changed it so its easier to read.

Comment: Great! Thank you very much for making it clear and helping me with this really appreciate it!